# Apache Spark: loading multiple files or a directory in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to load multiple files/directories in SPARK using Java, I have found a few examples on how to do this in scala, can someone give an example with explanation on how to do this in Java?

In particular I would like to use regex like paths, so that I do not have to specify a fully qualified name for each file. I can already give a comma separated file values with fully qualified names.

I am loading from the local file system, I don't know if this makes a difference

The following is the code I have used to load the files:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TableAggregator");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile(args[0], 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark, the method `textFile()` takes an URI for the file (either a local path on the machine or a `hdfs://`, etc URI).

You can run this method on directories, compressed files and wildcard :

> ctx.textFile("data.txt");
>
> ctx.textFile("/your/directory/");
>
> ctx.textFile("/your/directory/*");
>
> ctx.textFile("/your/directory/*.gz");

Be aware that when you use a path for your input, it has to be the same path for all the worker nodes. So you have to copy the file to all workers or use a shared network-mounted file system.

So you can use a pattern with the wildcard to do it simply.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. is the directory look up recursive?

Comment: For me, it is not recursive. You have a exception java.io.IOException: not a file

Comment: @AntoineHars Where is this documented?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found it on the documentation but I tried by myself and I get this error. If you search the term "textfile" in the Spark programming Guide (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) and in the javadoc (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html), there is no mention of the behavior in case of nested directories